# Using machine learning to detect fish spawning in audio files

Tags: python, machine-learning, audio, classification

My friend is doing his thesis related to fish spawning in rivers, for this, he collects hours of data that he then analysis manually in Audacity and looks for specific patterns in the spectrograms that might indicate the sound of fish spawning.

Since he has days' worth of data I proposed a challenge to myself: to create an algorithm that might help him in detecting these patterns.

I am fairly new to Machine Learning, but a junior in programming and this sounds like a fun learning experience.

I identify the main problems as:

- **samples are 1 hour in length.**
- **noise in the background** (such as cars and the rivers)

Is this achievable with machine learning or should I look into other options? If yes which ones?

Thank you for taking the time to read!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic for stack overflow. See [How to ask] for more information. This question might be more relevant on a general discussion forum, or if you do some research and focus/clarify it a bit, it might fit on [datascience.se]

Answer (score 1):

the first step would be to convert the sound signals into features that machines can understand. Maybe look into MFCCs for that.

Given that you have an appropriate feature representation of your problem domain, the main thing to consider would be what kind of machine learning algorithm would you apply? Unless you would like to sit and annotate hours of data, naive supervised learning is out of the window.

I think your best bet would be to modify VAD (voice activity detection) algorithms or better yet, Speaker recognition/Identification modals.

You could also approach it by first having a complex enough representation that allows you to "see" the sound and comparing it with every frame in the test data of the specific length. Might be useful to check out DTW (Dynamic Time warping)

If you have not designed such modals before, it will be a bit difficult and might take quite a long time.